Is this Narration, Musanaf ibn abi Shayba 3734, authentic?
There's this Narration in Musanaf al Shaybah which says that Abu Bakr (RA) and Umar ibn khattab (RA) burned the house of Fatima (RA) and Killed her.I need help to understand if this narration is weak or not.
The narration:

"3734 - Muhammad bin Bishr narrated to us Ubayd Allah bin Omar narrated to us Zaid bin Aslam narrated to us on the authority of his father, may God bless him and grant him peace, when he pledged allegiance to Abu Bakr after the Messenger of God, Ali and Al-Zubair used to go to Fatima, the entire house of the Messenger of God, and consult her and reconsider their matter. When this reached Omar bin Al-Khattab, he left until He entered upon Fatima and said: O daughter of the Messenger of God, no, by God, there is no one more beloved to her than your father, and no one is more beloved to us after your father than you. By God, I do not know that. If these people come together, they will stop you if I order them to burn the house over them. He said: When Omar came out, they brought her, and she said. You know that Omar has responded to me, and he has promised, by God, to his servants that they will burn the house for you, and he swore to God that they would carry out what he swore to do, so they departed of sound mind, so make up your mind and do not return to me, so they would turn away from it, so they did not go to it until they came to Abu Bakr.

Please help me with this narration , is it saheeh or not.  JazakAllahu Khayran

The hadith nowhere said that Omar burned the house of Fatima. What is the source of your translation or interpretation? The hadith only shows that Omar's threat  -at nor more is shown in the text you've posted- "helped" to get support for Abu Bakr's acceptance as a Calif.

Search "anti majoos productions broken rib" on YouTube he refutes this claim that Shias make that Abu bakr and Umar RA attacked the house of Ali and Fatima RA
